# Re-writing to remove index.php, not working properly Kohana

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, kohana

I'm trying to get rid of `index.php` from a url.

Now Kohana is serving the urls without the `index.php` preceding them, however, these urls are going to a not found page.

When I manually type in `index.php` before the url so something like `/index.php/login` would work

But the system itself directs to `/login` which leads to a not found error.

I've got the following in my .htaccess file, copied from Kohana

`RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]` which does nothing for me.

If anyone has any clue as to what's going on behind the scenes, it'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Start rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 # Make sure directory listing is disabled
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]



</IfModule>
```

and if still not working add this line after `RewriteEngine on`

```
RewriteBase /
```

or

```
RewriteBase /your-application-folder/
```

Comment: @user1952811 do you have enabled "mod_rewrite" in your apache server??

Comment: @user1952811 have you tried this way ?? http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls

Comment: yup, I created a phpinfo() file.

Here are the loaded module: core mod_so mod_watchdog http_core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version mod_unixd mod_access_compat mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_filter mod_mime prefork mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_status